# Json item prioritize

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, twig

I'm currently working with Twig. in an array of json can show 3 different types of elements.

```
"items":[
    {
     "type": "youtube"
    },
    {
     "type": "Picture"
    },
    {
     "type": "Gallery"
    }
]
```

I want to first select the type youtube in case there is no youtube select picture.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: That's an array of objects and not [JSON](http://json.org) -> [javascript - What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column if you use PHP 7+ to flatteren the array and then search it for the value 'youtube'.
If not found then search for 'Picture'.

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

$type = array_column($arr, 'type');
$key = array_search('youtube', $type);

if($key === false){
    $key = array_search('Picture', $type);
}
```

The return value is the key in $arr that you are looking for.
Like `var_dump($arr[$key]);`

https://3v4l.org/Cbs1u